# Number of processes on server

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, mysql, mysql5

I am bit worried about the number of processes on my server. I see plenty apache and mysql processes after a reboot. I am worried they will start eating up too much resources and bring the  server down. Is this the default config for apache and mysql? I did not mess with config files at all. Should I consider setting the number of child processes for each in their respective config?  [image]

Comment: Probably relevant: [this](https://superuser.com/q/118086/432690), [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364660/108618) and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154725/10765659).

Comment: Those extra processes will likely allow the system to handle more simultaneous connections.  The output you provided shows a system that is lightly loaded with plenty of memory available.  If you load up the system and see the CPU's or memory taxed, maybe tune down the processes a little.  Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: My issue is that once a month the memory gets eaten up and I have to reboot the server.   I need to figure out where the culprit is. Whether it's a open mysql handle in apache or whether it's a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default Apache config is very generic. It spawns a number of child processes for resilience but it does not know anything of your use case. [Apache recommends](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html) you tune the number of workers to avoid swapping that is detrimental to performance:

> A webserver should never ever have to swap, as swapping increases the
> latency of each request beyond a point that users consider "fast
> enough". This causes users to hit stop and reload, further increasing
> the load. You can, and should, control the MaxRequestWorkers setting
> so that your server does not spawn so many children that it starts
> swapping.

MySQL generally starts with a single process, so I am surprised to see that many. You may want to check how many are running on startup, to see if it created the extra processes in response to a certain workload. There is probably a config to control that but I don't know that one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll look into it. I also am surprised about how many `mysql` processes there are. In fact it's MariaDB I realize now (should have stated that in the issue). However, I am worried there's a bug somewhere that keeps connections to the backend open...

Comment: But hang on, `mysqld` is the daemon process, so the parent process, not a child one... ?

Comment: The daemon process just means it's a background process as opposed to a client application, such as command line tool issuing commands. The child process in this model is called the same, just like apache which used to be named `httpd`' that's since when a process calls fork() both proceses are the same name